# Where Could I Find A Zero Star Hotel?

Tags: hotels

Say I was looking for weird and wonderful places to travel. If the Burj Al Arab is the first ever 7 star hotel, where could I travel to find a 0 star hotel?

[image: Burj Al Arab, Dubai]

Comment: Most major hotel rating systems don't have 7 stars, so claiming seven stars is purely marketing hoopla and means nothing.

Answer (score 5):

[image: The World's First 0 Star Hotel]

> The world’s first 'no star' hotel has opened in a disused nuclear
>   shelter. (Sevelen, Switzerland) None of the rooms have views, there is only limited hot
>   water, no room service, no TV and guests are warned to be expected to
>   share with soldiers, firemen and emergency workers if nuclear war
>   breaks out. But the hotel scores over many of its competitors in
>   pricey Switzerland: it costs just £17 a night.

[Find out more](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1077791/Pictured-The-worlds-star-hotel-guests-sleep-disused-nuclear-shelter.html)

Comment: Many hotels never had stars, for a long time already, as they did not apply to get stars or were not meeting the requirements for stars.

Comment: And the notion of stars will depend on where you are. Some countries/regions/cities have very organized star rating systems with inspectors and strict criteria for each tier. Others may have voluntary associations do ratings (like AAA diamond ratings). And others will have no such organization and every hotel owner markets their property as they see fit.